# Aligning items of a row and column

Tags: css, laravel, bootstrap-5

[image]

i dont know how to fix the ui of this. Im using bootstrap 5. why aren't they align i can't seem to find the problem. tried many things but nothing work. here the code

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlush">
        @forelse($indicators As $indicator)
        <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne{{$indicator->id}}">
              <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne{{$indicator->id}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne{{$indicator->id}}">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-1 m-0">
                        <div class="p-2" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis-vertical "></i>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i> Add Sub Indicator</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/edit_indicator/{{$indicator->id}}"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i> Edit</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('delete_indicator', ['id' => $indicator->id]) }}"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash "></i> Delete</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        {{$indicator->indicator_name}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        {{$indicator->indicator_desc}}
                    </div>
                </div>
              </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="flush-collapseOne{{$indicator->id}}" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne{{$indicator->id}}" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlush">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the first item's accordion body.
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        @empty
             No Data yet
        @endforelse
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your html is probably malformed due to putting everything into a button. Refer to the example from the docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/#example

Answer (score -2):

It seems like you want to align the elements within each accordion item properly. I can see that you're using Bootstrap 5, so let's make sure the elements are structured correctly and that the Bootstrap classes are applied appropriately. Here's a modified version of your code with some improvements for better alignment:

```html
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionFlush">
        @forelse($indicators as $indicator)
        <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne{{$indicator->id}}">
                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne{{$indicator->id}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne{{$indicator->id}}">
                    <div class="row align-items-center">
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton{{$indicator->id}}" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis-vertical"></i>
                                </button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton{{$indicator->id}}">
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i> Add Sub Indicator</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/edit_indicator/{{$indicator->id}}"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i> Edit</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('delete_indicator', ['id' => $indicator->id]) }}"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i> Delete</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            {{$indicator->indicator_name}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            {{$indicator->indicator_desc}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="flush-collapseOne{{$indicator->id}}" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne{{$indicator->id}}" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlush">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                    Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the first item's accordion body.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @empty
            No Data yet
        @endforelse
    </div>
</div>
```

Changes and explanations:

1. I removed the `accordion-flush` class from the accordion container, as it's not needed for alignment purposes.
2. I added Bootstrap classes (`btn btn-secondary`) to the dropdown button for proper styling and alignment.
3. Enclosed the dropdown button and menu in a `div` with the class `dropdown` for correct dropdown functionality.

With these changes, your UI elements should align properly within each accordion item. Make sure you have the Bootstrap CSS and JavaScript properly included in your project for Bootstrap to work as expected.